# I'm building a rock, paper, scissors game - cannot make a variable increment after if statement is true

Tags: javascript, if-statement, increment

I am making rock, paper, scissors game. I can't make 'yourScore' and 'computerScore' increment after true if statements. Everything else works. I've been trying different variations for the last 2 hours.

```
let CPUchoice = []
let gameResult = document.getElementById('game-result');

let yourScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;

function computerChoice() {
    const picks = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
    CPUchoice = picks[Math.floor(Math.random()*picks.length)];
}

function rock() {
    computerChoice();
        if (CPUchoice === 'rock') {
            gameResult.textContent = "Computer chose rock, It's a draw!";
            } else if (CPUchoice === 'paper') {
                computerScore = computerScore++;
            gameResult.textContent = "Computer chose paper, you lost!";
            
            } else {
                yourScore = yourScore++;
            gameResult.textContent = "Computer chose scissors, you won!";
            }
}

function paper() {
    computerChoice();
        if (CPUchoice === 'paper') {
            gameResult.textContent = "Computer chose paper, It's a draw!";
            } else if (CPUchoice === 'scissors') {
            gameResult.textContent = "Computer chose scissors, you lost!"
            computerScore++;
            } else {
            gameResult.textContent = "Computer chose rock, you won!"
                yourScore ++;

            }
}
function scissors() {
        computerChoice();
        if (CPUchoice === 'scissors') {
            gameResult.textContent = "Computer chose scissors, It's a draw!";
            } else if (CPUchoice === 'rock') {
            gameResult.textContent = "Computer chose rock, you lost!"
            computerScore++;
            } else {
            gameResult.textContent = "Computer chose paper, you won!"
            yourScore ++;
            }
}

document.getElementById('your-score').textContent = 'Your score is... ' + yourScore;
document.getElementById('computer-score').textContent = 'Computer score is ....' + computerScore;
```

I have tried many variations of putting the .textContent method in the beginning, in the end. In the code there are 2 versions of incrementing the variable.

Comment: `computerScore = computerScore++;` doesn't actually do anything - `computerScore++` increments the variable but its result is the original value, which is then assigned back to `computerScore`. Just do `computerScore++`, or `computerScore = computerScore + 1;`. (Same with the other variable of course.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the last two lines (`document.getElementById...`) of your code is only executed **once**, i.e. when the script itself is loaded into the browser. What you should do is to update the `textContent`s whenever the scores change. The `=` sign here means a one-time assignment: assign the right hand side value to the left hand side variable. It doesn't mean the values on both sides are equal from thereon (sometimes this can be effectively true, but that's because of *references*. See [this post](https://ui.dev/primitive-vs-reference-values-in-javascript) about differences between a reference and a primitive value).

The simpliest fix is to put them in a function:

```js
function updateScores() {
  document.getElementById('your-score').textContent = 'Your score is... ' + yourScore;
  document.getElementById('computer-score').textContent = 'Computer score is ....' + computerScore;
}
```

... and execute this function whenever you increment `computerScore` and `yourScore`.

Other fixes include using reactive programming libraries and even using modern web frameworks, but those are too much of an overkill for this simple game.

Second, `score = score++` is basically a no-op. `score++` is equivalent to:

```js
function incrementScore() {
  const oldVal = score;
  score++;
  return oldVal;
}
```

And `score = score++` means you're assigning the oldVal to `score` again. The fix is to change those lines to `score++` (eliminating `score =` ).

Comment: Oh my god thank you! This worked and of course it makes perfect sense now that I read it.

Answer (score 0):

`num++` returns the value of `num`, and *then* increments the number, so your assignment gets the "old" value.

You can use `++num` to increment first and *then* assign. Or just add `1`.

But wait, plot twist! Because the `++` operator mutates its operand, the assignment itself is unnecessary. You can simply do `num++`.